# MS Access VBA boolean values localization problem

Tags: ms-access

I build some SQL query strings in VBA in an MS Access Database (current Office 365 Access Version) and I ran into a weird **localization problem with boolean values read from form controls**: `Me.MyBooleanControl` returns "Wahr" (german "True") => the generated SQL fails.

I'm using a workaround now, wrapping each value request by a function to translate the values to `-1`/ `0` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1529288/1349511), but I really like to know if there's a straight way to avoid this. I used the same code structure last year in another Access Database not running into the same problem - and I've absolutely no idea what's different (besides MS Office my have been updated).

**Edit**: I found the solution, see answer below.

Comment: A checkbox returns values that can't be localised. So, somehow you cast those values. Without your code we can't tell why.

Comment: Thank you for the hint @Gustav, I found the bug by providing the code (see edit).

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer and accept it so someone else who faces a similar problem may find the solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks @forpas, I'll do.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to reproduce the problem independently from the rest of my code, I nailed it down and found it to be **my fault: I initialized the unbound checkbox as `True`** which seemed to work fine, but causes the problem:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.UnboundCheckbox01 = True
    Me.UnboundCheckbox02 = -1
End Sub

Private Sub ReadCheckBox()
    Debug.Print Me.UnboundCheckbox01 ' returns localized value "Wahr"
    Debug.Print Me.UnboundCheckbox02 ' returns -1 as expected

    ' after manually toggeling UnboundCheckbox01 to unchecked
    ' and back to checked again, the value returns as -1 too
End Sub
```

Sorry! Next time I'll honor the rules and provide some code - sometimes the question dissolves by just doing that...

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate this with my Danish localisation:

```
Me!UnboundCheckbox01 = True
Debug.Print Me!UnboundCheckbox01 ' returns String: "True"
```

However, it appears that you can assign just about any value of any data type to an unbound checkbox:

```
Me!UnboundCheckbox01 = "Martin"
Debug.Print Me!UnboundCheckbox01 ' returns String: "Martin"

Me!UnboundCheckbox01 = Now
Debug.Print Me!UnboundCheckbox01 ' returns Date like: 2020-03-29 13.45.23
```

I'm not sure if this is intended - even though the Value property is said to be of data type *Variant*:

[CheckBox.Value property (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.checkbox.value)

Comment: Thank's for checking this out! So your comment above was not 100% correct: in the special case of assigning `True` to a checkbox it *may* happen that you run into a localization problem (maybe depending on program version or setup) ;)